# Add a space after a word if it's at the beginning of a string or if it's after one or more spaces, and at the same time it must be at end or before \n

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regexp-replace

```py
import re

line = "treinta y un"       #example 1
line = "veinti un "         #example 2
line = "un"                 #example 3
line = "un "                #example 4
line = "uno"                #example 5
line = "treinta yun"        #example 6
line = "treinta y unghhg"   #example 7

re_for_identificate_1 = "(?<!^)un"
re_for_identificate_2 = " un"

line = re.sub(re_for_identificate_2, " un ", line)
line = re.sub(re_for_identificate_1, "un ", line)

print(repr(line))
```

How to obtain this outputs from those inputs?

```
"treinta y un "       #for example 1
"veinti un "          #for example 2
"un "                 #for example 3
"un "                 #for example 4
"uno"                 #for example 5
"treinta yun"         #for example 6
"treinta y unghhg"    #for example 7
```

Note that for examples 4, 5, 6 and 7 the regex should not make any changes, since after the word there is already a space placed, or because in the case of `"uno"`, the word `"un"` is not at the end of the sentence, or in the case of `"treinta yun"` the substring `"un"` is not preceded by one or more spaces.

Comment: kindly clearify your question

Comment: I needed the regular expression that allows me to get the correct output for each of those examples. Only in examples 1, 2 and 3 should you make the replacements but the other 4 examples are the cases where the replacements should not be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex, you can use `\bun$`, which checks that the last *whole* word in the string is `un`, and that there is nothing after it in the string. If that is the case, a space is added to the end of the string:

```py
import re

lines = ["treinta y un", "veinti un ", "un", "un ",
         "uno", "treinta yun", "treinta y unghhg"]

result = [re.sub(r'\bun$', 'un ', line) for line in lines]
```

Output:

```
[
 'treinta y un ',
 'veinti un ',
 'un ',
 'un ',
 'uno',
 'treinta yun',
 'treinta y unghhg'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need regular expressions. The following code appears to achieve what you want.

Three checks are performed:

1. The content is a string
2. The last two characters are "un"
3. The last word is "un"

Here I've wrapped the logic in a list comprehension to demonstrate.

```
lines = ["treinta y un", "veinti un ", "un", "un ",
         "uno", "treinta yun", "treinta y unghhg"]

result = [ line+" " if (isinstance(line, str) 
                    and (line[-2:] == "un") 
                    and (line.split()[-1] == "un"))
          else line 
          for line in lines ]

for line in result:
    print(f"'{line}'")
```

Output:

```
'treinta y un '
'veinti un '
'un '
'un '
'uno'
'treinta yun'
'treinta y unghhg'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the `line =`  like that in you code, you will overwrite it each time.

Using `(?<!^)un` asserts not the start of the string directly to the left.

If you also want to exclude a match for `#un` you can use `(?<\S)` instead asserting a whitspace boundary to the left.

To make sure the pattern is at the end of the string, you can use the anchor `$`

The code example uses single lines, but if you want to do the replacement when having multiple lines, you have to use the multiline flag `re.MULTILINE` with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!\S)un$"

lines = ["treinta y un", "veinti un ", "un", "un ",
         "uno", "treinta yun", "treinta y unghhg", "#un"]

print([re.sub(pattern, 'un ', line) for line in lines])
```

Output

```
[
  'treinta y un ',
  'veinti un ',
  'un ',
  'un ',
  'uno',
  'treinta yun',
  'treinta y unghhg',
  '#un'
]
```